# How do the probabilities in decay schemes work? (Ir-192)

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation

I'm incredibly confused as to how the probabilities work in decay schemes (Particularly for Iridium-192).

There are the green numbers to the left of the image that appear to add up to the total probability of Beta decay (95.13%) - although I don't know what they actually mean?

Similarly, you have numbers directly above the arrows (For example 82.75 from states 1->0). Are these probabilities (If so, of what)? If they are, shouldnt they add up to 100% in some way?

Thank You!!

[image]

Comment: What is the source of the level scheme? Please don't cut and paste random stuff on the internet without attribution. It's rude.

Answer (score 1):

The green arrows denote the probabilities that the platinum-192 nucleus will be left in that particular state after the beta particle is emitted.  So, for example, there is a 47.9% chance that the platinum-192 nucleus will be in State #3 after the beta decay.  If the daughter nucleus is left in a higher energy state, this means that there will be less energy transferred to the beta particle and the neutrino emitted.

After the daughter nucleus arrives in its initial excited state, it then decays to the ground state via one or more gamma-ray emissions.  The numbers above each vertical arrow tell you the percentage of the disintegrations that involve the emission of a gamma ray of that energy.  For example, out of every 100 decays, the platinum nucleus will end up making the State #3 to State #1 transition 47.81 times.  Note that a given daughter may emit more than one gamma ray as it descends to the ground state, so we would not expect all of the numbers to add up to 100%.

If the only way for a daughter nucleus to get rid of its excitation energy was via gamma-ray emission, we would expect the sum of the probabilities entering any particular state to be equal to the sum of the probabilities leaving the state.  But you'll notice, if you run the numbers, that this is not the case.  I suspect that the unaccounted-for decays are via [internal conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_conversion), in which the excited nucleus transfers energy to the orbiting electrons.  The excitation energy is then emitted via characteristic X-rays and Auger electrons.

Comment: Amazing, that's a lot clearer - thank you!